# Azure Application insight not working from UWP device

Tags: azure, uwp, azure-application-insights

I have setup the application insights for my app, I can see all the data when I am running my app from the PC, when I am debugging the app running on device, I still see the data in the VS output window and can see "Data from Debug session telemetry" option in Visual studio, but the data from the device is not showing up at app insight portal. Any idea, what might be wrong?

Comment: Are you developing a uwp app?  AFAIK, azure application insight used for uwp app is actually [hocyapp](https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-windows-and-windows-phone/how-to-create-an-app-for-windows-application) according to [app-insights-platforms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-platforms).

Answer (score 0):

Things to check:

1. does your UWP app allow outbound network calls?  depending on the template/version you started with, the UWP app might not be allowed to send outbound data at all, preventing data from being sent to appinsights.
2. is it going out at all?  use fiddler or something similar (including the extra work to enable it to see traffic from UWP apps, and allow it to decode https)  look for outbound calls to dc.services.visualstudio.com
3. if it is going out, is it being accepted/succeeding?  or are the calls failing?
4. if it is going out, is it using the ikey you expect? so that the data is actually going to the same app you're looking at on the portal

As others have commented, if you want a newer SDK, the hockeyapp.uwp nuget package also allows you to [send data to application insights](https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-windows-and-windows-phone/how-to-integrate-hockeyapp-with-application-insights).